# Meteor Spacebars Helpers - Passing another spacebar as helper argument

Tags: meteor, spacebars

I have been trying to pass the spacebar as another spacebar argument like this :

```
{{helperfunction {{argument}} }}
```

here the {{argument}} is also coming from another helper function.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use the additional `{{}}`.

lets say that `argument` is a string and helper function is expecting a string then `{{helperFn argument}}` is like `helperFn(argument)`. So the single `{{ ... }}` is sufficient. `{{}}` using the bracket is like opening a javascript context (kind of) so if `arguments` is already a defined var that is in scope, there is no need to add additional `{{}}`.

if you do want to compose blaze helper functions, you can do that by using parens like so `{{helperFn1 (helperFn2 argument)}}`. 
this would be like `helperFn1( helperFn2(argument) )`

also, if `argument` is a function, I believe that blaze will call the function and return the result automatically. => `{{helperFn argument}}` is like `helperFn(argument())`.

hope that helps a bit.

Comment: You are right @mason505, I got your point, any additional spacebars values even if they are from the parent can be passed using the same double braces {{}} for example now I am using {{helperfunction argument }}, It works Thanks for your help.